# The images are not loading properly

Tags: product-images

we have such a problem on magento 2, it started to do this to us when we added more sites, images and products.

It is that when I open our site [www.bridgeacademy.cz](http://www.bridgeacademy.cz), go to products https://www.bridgeacademy.cz/cz/krouzky-na-skolach.html , scroll down the page and the images for the products don't show up. However, when I open the site in anonymous mode, they do load. This is a very random phenomenon that also manifests itself in that when I refresh the page halfway through, other (more distant images) do not load. It looks to me as if magento has set some image size that it loads and the rest doesn't load.
On phone the images does not load when i am scrolling down, but when i scroll up the images load IDK srsly.
[image]
I would be glad for any advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this command:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

It creates resized product images.

Comment: Will try and let you know. 

Weird is that it worked fine month ago and now it doesn't. 

Seems more like cache, cookie, memory issue.

Comment: This will resolve because it updates the images

Comment: Have you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to do this, even change to the dev. mode and it still does not work.

The problem occured only on this site - https://www.bridgeacademy.cz/cz/online-krouzky.html

It always loads only the same number of products and when you resize it it loads normally. When you refresh in the middle, then the top images does not load.

Can you help me find out the issue please?

Comment: Please update your question by editing it rather than posting an answer.